# Dumpcap capture filter syntax - wlan addr1 question

Tags: ieee-802.11, wireshark

I am trying to capture wireless traffic from specified MAC addresses only, and I seem to be using the wrong syntax. When I use:

```
dumpcap -i wlp2s0 -b filesize:100000 -w capture.pcapng -a duration:18000 -f wlan addr1 d4:be:d9:5b:a6:45
```

I get:

```
dumpcap: Invalid argument: d4:be:d9:5b:a6:45
```

I appear to be getting the syntax that goes after -f incorrect. I am referencing http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html which is linked from the WireShark wiki page on dumpcap.

I can't seem to find examples for wireless MAC address capturing, only wired. I'm sure there is something I am missing here.

Follow up question: if I want to sniff for a few MAC addresses, do I separate them with the term, eg: `wlan addr1 xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx` or `wlan addr1 xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.zz`?

Using wireshark 2.2.6 on Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are apparently using the `-f` option incorrectly. This is what the Dumpcap documentation says about it:

> -f
>
> Set the capture filter expression.
>
> **The entire filter expression must be specified as a single argument (which means that if it contains spaces, it must be quoted).**
>
> This option can occur multiple times. If used before the first occurrence of the -i option, it sets the default capture filter
>   expression. If used after an -i option, it sets the capture filter
>   expression for the interface specified by the last -i option occurring
>   before this option. If the capture filter expression is not set
>   specifically, the default capture filter expression is used if
>   provided.

The page that you link also shows the filters as quoted (copied directly from the linked page):

```
`wlan addr2 0:2:3:4:5:6'.
```

Try something like:

```
dumpcap -i wlp2s0 -b filesize:100000 -w capture.pcapng -a duration:18000 -f `wlan addr1 d4:be:d9:5b:a6:45'
```

Apparently, you can use the filter option multiple times.

Comment: Ah it was the single quotes. I had tried it with double quotes and had that fail as an unrecognized option. Thank you!